# Central - Peripharal / Client - Server Architecture, BLE communication Tizen Wearable with iOS not working

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

My requirement is to create a Application which can transfer data / text from Tizen Wearable to iOS App. To accomplish this requirement i created a BLE communication architecture i.e. central - peripharal. So issue here is:

1. iOS Central - Tizen Peripharal :   In this Tizen Peripharal register a service to adapter and Advertise the same service to be scanned. I received the advertised service on central but registered service is not received on central side when i scan for services. Here is some code :

```
var adapter2 = tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();

var CHAT_SERVICE_UUID = "5BCE9431-6C75-32AB-AFE0-2EC108A30860";



function chatServiceSuccessCb(recordHandler)

{

  console.log("Chat service registration succeeds!");

  chatServiceHandler = recordHandler;

}



function publishChatService()

{

  adapter2.registerRFCOMMServiceByUUID(CHAT_SERVICE_UUID, "Chat service", chatServiceSuccessCb,

      function(e)

      {

        console.log("Could not register service record, Error: " + e.message);

      });

}



publishChatService();



var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getLEAdapter();

var advertiseData = new tizen.BluetoothLEAdvertiseData({

    includeName: true,

    uuids: [CHAT_SERVICE_UUID]

});

var connectable = true;

adapter.startAdvertise(advertiseData, 'ADVERTISE', function onstate(state) {

    console.log('Advertising configured: ' + state);

}, function(error) {

    console.log('startAdvertise() failed: ' + error.message);

}, 'LOW_LATENCY', connectable);
```

2. iOS Peripharal - Tizen Central : This time I created peripharal on iOS side, created the same service, advertised the service. I received the advertised data on Tizen side. I connect to remote device, Connection success listener called. Now when I try to connect to service i receive exception i.e. device not connected exception.

In code remoteDevice.getService(remoteDevice.uuids[0]) create exception while remoteDevice.addConnectStateChangeListener(onConnectionStateChange); these listeners never get called.

Here is some code:

```
function connectFail(error) {

    console.log('Failed to connect to device: ' + error.message);

}



function connectSuccess() {

    console.log('Connected to device');

    var serviceUUIDs = remoteDevice.uuids;

    console.log('total number of services found here are: ' + serviceUUIDs.length);

    service = remoteDevice.getService(remoteDevice.uuids[0]);

    console.log('flag next step 1');

}



function onerror(e)

{

  console.log("Error occurred: " + e.message);

}



function onDeviceFound(device)

{

  console.log("Found new device: " + device.name);

  var onConnectionStateChange =

  {

    onconnected: function(device)

    {

            heartrateVal.innerHTML = 'connected';

      console.log("Device " + device.name + " connected");

    },

    ondisconnected: function(device)

    {

      console.log("Device " + device.name + " disconnected");

      device.removeConnectStateChangeListener(listenerID);

    }

  };



  if (device.name === "aBcD")

  {

    remoteDevice = device

    console.log("Found required device: " + device.name);

    listenerID = remoteDevice.addConnectStateChangeListener(onConnectionStateChange);

    remoteDevice.connect(connectSuccess, connectFail);

    adapter.stopScan();

  }

}



var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getLEAdapter();

var listenerID = null;

adapter.startScan(onDeviceFound, onerror);
```

I have tested my iOS application with another iOS application as well as android application which works fine. But with tizen i face these issues. I am not sure is there any issue in Tizen SDK or Tizen BLE works in different way than the iOS and android.

Note: All above mentioned code are from the Tizen Samples and API specifications. few links are

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.sampledescriptions/html/mobile_w/bluetoothchat_mw.htm

https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/connectivity-and-wireless/bluetooth

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario no. 1:
Tizen Bluetooth API does not provide support for GATT server API. You used API for RFCOMM (socket) API - registerRFCOMMServiceByUUID which is not a part of low energy standard. This is the cause why your first scenario does not work. For server GATT functionalities you can use [native API](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/5.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__NETWORK__BLUETOOTH__GATT__SERVER__MODULE.html)

For scenario no. 2:
I tried to reproduce this scenario with S4 watch and Android phone and connection callback (and listener) worked as expected. Please be more specific about the devices do you use, then the reproduction will be easier.